# VS2015 solution explorer "Archive All.." entry is missing

Tags: android, visual-studio-2015, archiving

The context menu entry "Archive All.." in one of my VS2015 installations is missing.

I can still build and deploy Android apps. The "View archives" is still available and, indeed, shows the archived releases. But I can no longer archive new releases.

Is there a way to hack the VS config to re-enable it?

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was a corrupt Xamarin update removing part of the Android SDK. Once restored, the menu entry came back.